# Wrong $HOME for shell_exec in PHP

Tags: php, apache

Apache 2.2.3, PHP 5.2.17, RHEL 5 64bit

If I do a `echo shell_exec('echo $HOME');` in a page on my server and I view it in my browser I get : `/root`, which is not what I thought I should have (`/var/www`)
A `whoami` command returns apache
Same result with `exec`
Any idea ?

Comment: `echo shell_exec('echo $HOME');` that statment is errornous. you can not use `echo` inside `echo`

Comment: Don't see your point. I call a shell echo via shell_exec and use a PHP echo to show shell_exec return. Where is the error ?

Comment: @Shakti - 'echo $HOME' is a shell command not a PHP commant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache starts as root and then changes to the Apache user but that doesn't update the environment variables. See here: https://serverfault.com/questions/179833/apache2-user-home-directory-lock-to-root

If you want the document root of Apache you should use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept this answer. Gave me the explanation. So I'll have to update env before running my external shell script.